# Given $g(n)=-n+3$ and $h(n)=-2n+6$, find $c(n)=g(n)+h(n)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $g(n)=-n+3$ and $h(n)=-2n+6$, find $c(n)=g(n)+h(n)$

For my attempt, I got $-2n+8$

correct?

Comment: I improved the formatting, but the $g$ in the title was different from the $g$ in the question. Please make sure that the edit is what you intended

Comment: Is this a simple addition of ${-n+3}$ and ${-2n+6}$? If so, $c(n)$ should be $-3n+9$.

Comment: Could you clarify how you got $-2n+8$?

Answer (score 3):

Given $\;g(n)=-n+3\;$ and $\;h(n)=-2n+6:\;$

we find $c(n)=g(n) + h(n)$, we simply **add** the two given functions:

$$\begin{align} c(n) & =g(n)+h(n) \\ \\
& = \underbrace{(-n + 3)}_{g(n)} + \underbrace{(-2n + 6)}_{h(n)} \\ \\
& = (-3n + 9)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, Amzoti! $\langle\hat{\overline{\ddot\smile}}\rangle$

Comment: @Amzoti Awesome! I've played around with programming art, as well! Sometimes using words: I've written some of my favorite quotes pictorial, using the text, but formatting it pictorially!